# ¿puedo trabajar el cmd desde python?

Tags: python-3.x

soy principiante, primer semestre de ing en sistemas, mi primer lenguaje es python, me preguntaba ¿puedo abrir el cmd y en una ruta en específico usando python?
estoy teniendo algunas molestias al tener que abrir el terminal y dirigirme hasta mis archivos, y quería saber si puedo ejecutar algo para abrir el cmd en la ruta de mis archivos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongo que quieres ejecutar un .py desde cmd sin tener que entrar a la carpeta desde consola, si es asi necesitas pegar este codigo:

@echo off
cd \
command /k cd c:\carpeta

en la parte que dice c:\, tienes que poner el nombre de la carpeta a la que quieres acceder abres el bloc de notas y pegas ese codigo y por ultimo lo guardas como un .bat,asi podras acceder con un clic a la carpeta donde estan tus proyectos y ejecutarlos desde la consola ;D !!